# Some standard elliptic estimates

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the problem

$$\Delta_{g}u - c(n)R_{g}u + Ku^{p} = 0  \mbox{    at   } M$$

where $c(n) = \frac{n-2}{4(n-1)}$, $K$ is a constant, $R_{g}$ is a
scalar curvature, and $(M^{n},g)$ is a smooth compact Riemannian
manifold without boundary.
\

1) How can I find a constant $C>0$ such that
$$C^{-1} \leq u \leq C$$

I think is a consequence of the Harnack inequality.
?
\

2) How can I prove that
$$\|u\|_{C^{2,\alpha}} \leq C.$$

My goal is to prove that... Its suffices to estimate $|u|_{C^{0}(M)}$ and use some
regularity  for the estimation be demonstrated?